# Programming Nrf52832 using Arduino?

Tags: arduino, nrf52832

Has anyone programmed a bare nrf52832. I have the ebytes e73-2g4m04s1b module. Nordics devzone suggest using segger j link and stuff. But I don't have access to any of those. Can I use Arduino Uno to programme ? Has anyone done it before ? Can u guide / point to some resources.

Comment: No dice. You need an SWD programmer - and nordic supplied software only supports J-Link. Pointing to external ressources is off topic here anyway.

Comment: Can I use Arduino as an SWD ? Are there any chances ?

Comment: A cheap fake stlink will work, better actually than it will on ST parts.  The problem with making a programmer from an Arduino is you would need both voltage translation and software to fill the task.   Most SWD programmers are made from other ARM Cortex M series chips...

Answer (score 1):

I do the job with J-Link, it needs large luck, I write the guide for how to develop nRF52832 with Arduino IDE [here](https://github.com/eyesblue/nRF52832ArduinoDev), but there is no mention about how to flash bootloader, the story starts after flash bootloader, you can check it, it may help you.